# Как правильно поместить метод в таблицу?

Tags: lua

Вот такой пример не работает, в нём при вызове функции self == nil:

```
function test()
  return {
    foo = "bar",
    say = function()
      print(self.foo)
    end
  }
end
```

А вот так всё работает, но такая запись мне не нравится ):

```
function test()
  local result = {foo = "bar"}
  function result:say()
    print(self.foo)
  end
  return result
end
```

Проверка:

```
local t = test()
t:say()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У функции должен быть параметр `self`:

```
function test()
  return {
    foo = "bar",
    say = function(self)
      print(self.foo)
    end
  }
end
```

Вызовы вида `t:say()` на самом деле всегда разворачивается в `t.say(t)` и если вы хотите внутри функции `say()` иметь доступ к полям таблицы, вам нужно объявить как минимум один параметр (с любым именем), в который вам и будет передана эта таблица. В Lua, общепринятое имя для такого параметра - `self`, но вы можете использовать любое.

Если у функции есть несколько параметров, то таблица будет всегда передаваться в качестве "нулевого" параметра, т.е вызов `t:say(x, y)` будет транслироваться в `t.say(t, x, y)` и при объявлении функции вы всегда должны ожидать параметр `self` на первом месте:

```
    say = function(self, x, y)
      print(self.foo)
    end
```

Что касается синтаксиса с двоеточием, то это т.н. синтаксический сахар. В Lua на самом деле нету классов, и их можно лишь эмулировать (в некоторой степени) при помощи таблиц. И чтобы эта эмуляция выглядела похожей, на использование классов, и был введён такой синтаксис.

Comment: Не знал, что self можно явно передавать в виде параметра. Спасибо.

Comment: Отлично. Предлагаю добавить это в ответ и почистить комментарии :)

Comment: Как-то странно выходит, что если первый аргумент функции self, то он не считается первым. Например, если после self указать второй аргумент, а затем вызвать функцию, передав ей что-нибудь, то это что-нибудь будет воспринято именно как второй аргумент (а если указать self вторым аргументом, то можно хорошо запутаться).

Comment: `self` это неявный (скрытый) аргумент, который всегда **автоматически** передаётся первым. Вы не можете по своему желанию передать его вторым или не передать вообще, т.е. выбора у вас нету. И это абсолютно нормальное явление и существует в таком виде во многих языках программирования, где есть классы. В С++ и Java вместо `self` используется ключевое слово `this`.

Comment: Почему же? Не передать self я могу! Как раз в этом и была моя проблема, self не передавался. Я изучаю lua после javascript и хорошо знаком с this, но там он действительно передаётся автоматически, а в lua видимо нет!

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Нет, вы можете отказаться получать его, если вы объявите функцию без параметров. И в таком случае, внутри этой функции вы не должны обращаться к self. Таким образом, у вас получится т.н. [статический метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) - тоже, хорошо известное явление в ООП: *статические методы не имеют доступа к данным объекта, и для их использования не нужно создавать экземпляры (данного класса)*

Comment: Но учтите, что если у функции есть *хоть один* параметр, вне зависимости от того, какое у него имя, в этот параметр будет передан self. Т.е. в lua нельзя сделать статический метод и чтобы он был с параметрами, в отличии от других языков. Если есть параметры, то там, первым параметром, всегда будет self.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Теперь всё ясно. Спасибо :)